# Pass Storage value to object Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic-storage

I get value from storage in ionic 2.

```
        this.storage.get('name').then((nama) => {
            this.name = nama
        });
```

and i want pass the data "this.name" to the object, but when i run the app, it's not return anything

```
    this.userData = {
        id: '0404040404',
        nama: this.name,
        no_hp: '082211590346',
        email: 'rifqyzackya@gmail.com'
    }
```

here my full code

```
name:any
userData: {id: string, nama: string, no_hp: string, email: string}

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public storage: Storage) {

        this.storage.get('name').then((nama) => {
            this.name = nama
        });

    this.userData = {
        id: '0404040404',
        nama: this.name,
        no_hp: '082211590346',
        email: 'rifqyzackya@gmail.com'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

userData should be initiated in the promise result:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public storage: Storage) {

        this.storage.get('name').then((nama) => {
            this.name = nama
            this.userData = {
                id: '0404040404',
                nama: nama,
                no_hp: '082211590346',
                email: 'rifqyzackya@gmail.com'
            }
        });


}
```